# Azure Error, "Could not retrieve the settings for endpoint monitoring.: ErrorReadFaulted"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Just started to get this within Azure Websites when I click on "Configure".  I do not use "endpoints" at all.

Perhaps this is a temporary glitch???

What is it? Any thoughts?

Comment: New portal or old portal?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in the old portal.

Comment: It was the old portal, now gone however... Sorry for the delay in responding

Comment: I've been receiving this error ever since I removed the endpoints and re-created them again on my VM. How do you configure an endpoint for Azure monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure Management Portal, from the website's Management pages, click the Monitor tab to display the Monitor management page. By default the chart on the Monitor page displays the same metrics as the chart on the Dashboard page.

To view additional metrics for the website, click Add Metrics at the bottom of the page to display the Choose Metrics dialog box.

Click to select additional metrics for display on the Monitor page.

After selecting the metrics that you want to add to the Monitor page, click the check mark at the bottom.

After adding metrics to the Monitor page, click to enable / disable the round checkbox next to each metric to add / remove the metric from the chart at the top of the page.

To remove metrics from the Monitor page, select the metric that you want to remove and then click the Delete Metric icon at the bottom of the page.